# How to Make the cell to become date formatted when user input to the date column on datagridview in vb?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to make the cells to auto add the slashes when the user input date without slashes. Or it will be better if the cell format can be set to date to make the user input the date easier. Thank you for you help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//MYDATE is your date string  
//Code:

string MYDATE = "01042016";    
for (int i = 2; i < value.Length; i+=3) {
  value = value.Insert( i, "/")
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do I have to put this code on DataGridView cellendedit or somewhere..?

Comment: Hi Johns, This is only to be used to format a textbox. this snippet can be added to the onchange or keyup/down or press funtion